# jquery. ошибка получения scr картинки товара

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

текст получает как нужно, но при получении src, для последующей вставки в попап при клике происходит ошибка [image: https://ibb.co/pzZfYZv]

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Цепляемся за событие adding_to_cart
    $( document.body ).on( 'adding_to_cart', function( event, button ) {
        // Выцепляем инициатора события (ссылка/кнопка)
        var $btn = $( button[0] );
 
        // Пытаемся найти в вёрстке название товара
        var product_title = $btn.parents( 'li.product' ).find( '.woocommerce-loop-product__title' ).text();
        var product_title1 = $btn.parents( 'li.product' ).find( '.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail' ).getAttribute('src');
 
            // Формируем шаблон попапа
            var tpl = '';
            tpl += '<p>Товар "' + product_title + '" добавлен в корзину</p>';
            tpl += '<p>Товар "' + product_title1 + '" добавлен в корзину</p>';
            tpl += '<div>';
            tpl += '<a class="button" onclick="jQuery.unblockUI();">Продолжить</a>';
            tpl += '<a href="/shop/cart/" class="button alt">Оформить</a>';
            tpl += '</div>';
 
            // Выводим шаблон в модальное окно.
            // Используем blockUI из WooCommerce
            $.blockUI({
                message: tpl,
                timeout: 4000,
                css: {
                    width: '300px',
                    border: 0,
                    padding: 30
                }
            } );
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы не можете так использовать функцию `getAttribute`. для того чтоб получить аттрибут у вас есть два варианта:

1.

```
 var product_title1 = $btn.parents( 'li.product' ).find( '.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail' ).attr('src')
```

2. 

```
var product_title1 = $btn.parents( 'li.product' ).find( '.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail' )[0].getAttribute('src')
```

Comment: спасибо, брал то что в гугле